# How to do Domain Mapping to Subdirectories?

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping, directory

Does Wordpress MU not allow domain mapping to subdirectories, such as example.com/blog?

Wordpress.com [doesn't allow](http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/map-subdomain/) this.

I couldn't find an option to do this in WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domain mapping works for both subdomains and subfolders (AKA subdirectories). It used to not be available for subfolder installs via the [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin, but that's no longer the case for a long time. With that being said, it's for a self-hosted blog (WordPress.org install) and not for WordPress.com.

Comment: He wasn't asking about the kind of install. He's asking about mapping domains with a flder in it - which you cannot do.

Comment: Not really the case.

Answer (score 1):

> such as example.com/blog?

You cannot map domain names with subfolders in them. This is not a WordPress restriction, but a DNS one.